# Is there anyway we could limit an update?

Tags: cassandra

Generally, I see we can limit the select by `select * from table where predicate = value limit by N` Am currently in a situation where I have 200 records falling under a predicate, but I want to update the first 100 like `update table set column = 1 where predicate = value limit...?` and the second half by `update table set column = 2 where predicate = value`. I think it could be done by having ranges <=,>= in the predicate section, unfortunately, I have none of them.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't think we have this feature as WHERE clause must identify the row or rows to be updated by primary key as [per](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html). However, you could further limit the number of rows to be updated by using `IF EXISTS` condition. Details can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html#cqlUpdate__conditionally-updating-columns)